swiper functionality not working inside the product card
the swiper  in angular 17
not working inside the product card althought it worked in an another component
product-page.component.html :
   <div class="card-img-container overflow-auto">
          <div class="swiper-container myProductSwiper" #swiperContainer>
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <!-- Iterate over each image of the product -->
              <ng-container *ngFor="let image of product.images">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-item">
                    <img [src]="image" alt="Product Image">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
            <!-- Pagination and Navigation outside the ngFor loop -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

product-page.component.ts :
 import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
 export class ProductPageComponent implements OnInit ,AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('swiperContainer') swiperContainer!: ElementRef;
  swiper: Swiper | undefined;

  products: Product[] = [];
  isDealerLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  faArrowCircleLeft = faArrowCircleLeft;


  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private productImageService: ProductImageService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, // Inject Router service
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private dealerLoginService: DealerLoginService, // Inject DealerLoginService
  ) {     Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);
  }   
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit called ');
    this.initializeSwiper();
  }
private initializeSwiper(): void {
    if (this.swiperContainer && this.swiperContainer.nativeElement) {
      this.swiper = new Swiper(this.swiperContainer.nativeElement, {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },
        keyboard: {
          enabled: true,
          onlyInViewport: true,
        },
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Swiper container not found or not initialized.');
    }
  }

the swiper should be inside the card img container .
and yes i added the registerSwiperElements(); inside my main.ts and added schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],

Swiper is recommending to use swiper-element which means, we have a different way of initialization, could you try the below code.
Answers you can use for reference
FULL CODE:
HTML:
<swiper-container
  slides-per-view="1"
  speed="500"
  loop="true"
  navigation="true"
  pagination="true"
  #swiper
  scrollbar="true"
>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

TS:
import { Component, OnInit, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  standalone: true,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
})
export class SwiperComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {}
}

Stackblitz Demo

working code ===>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>

<a class="back-button" (click)="goBack()">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faArrowCircleLeft"></fa-icon>
</a>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let product of products">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <swiper-container class="mySwiper" pagination="true" pagination-type="progressbar" navigation="false" loop="true">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let image of product.images">
            <swiper-slide>
              <div class="product-item">
                <img [src]="image" alt="Product"  (click)="openProductImagesDialog(product.images)">
              </div>
            </swiper-slide>
          </ng-container>
        </swiper-container>


        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">{{ product.name }}</h1>
          <hr />
          <p class="card-text" [innerHTML]="product.description"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="price-and-vat-container">
            <h2 class="price">{{ product.price }}$</h2>
            <p class="small">+ V.A.T (Retail)</p>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isDealerLoggedIn" class="dealer-price-and-vat-container">
            <hr />
            <h3 class="dealer-price">{{ product.dealerPrice }}$</h3>
            <p class="small">+ V.A.T (Dealer)</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>
            <button *ngIf="product.thumbnailImage" (click)="openAdvertisementDialog(product.thumbnailImage!)">
              Advertisement
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

